# How to validate react date picker using react form hook

Tags: react-hooks, yup, react-datepicker, react-forms

I am using a data-picker for one of my projects and trying to validate using yup. but I'm to show an error message but it is not hiding after a date is selected. any help is much appreciated.

Here is my schema

```
let schema = yup.object().shape({
    expiry_date: yup.date().required("Please enter expiry date")
});


<Controller
    name="expiry_date"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <DatePicker {...field} selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => onDateChange(date)} />
    )}
/>

{errors.expiry_date && <p className="error">{errors.expiry_date?.message}</p>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is bit incomplete, but I was able to add date picker into a `formik` form and it was working:

```
// DatePickerTest.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { FormkiValues, useFormik} from 'formik';
import * as yup  from 'yup';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

interface IFormikValues {
  // ... some other
  expiry_date: Date;
}

const validationSchema = yup.object({
// ... some other
expiry_date: yup.date().required("Please enter expiry date")
});


const DatePickerText:React.FC = ():JSX.Element => {
  const formik = useFormik<IFormikValues>({
    initialValues: {
      // ... some other
      expiry_date: new Date()
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });
  return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      {/* some other fields */}
      <DatePicker
         id="expiry_date"
         name="expiry_date"
         selected={formik.values.expiry_date}
         onChange={(date) => {
           formik.setFieldValue('expiry_date',date);
         }}

      />
      {formik.errors.expiry_date && <p className="error">{formik.errors.expiry_date}</p>}
      {/* some other fields */}
      <button type="submit" disabled={formik.isSubmitting}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>);
};

export default DatePickerTest;
```

Yuu may check if your date value update function `onDateChange` is updating the formik values.